# Angular 4 put a global constant available to zone.js

Tags: angular, zone

i am using Angular (4 i think) with typescript and zone.js (0.8.4). I import zone.js via the "polyfills.ts" file. When I look inside the source code of zone.js, there is code like this:

```
var isDisableIECheck = _global['__Zone_disable_IE_check'] || false;
```

My question is, how can I set this variable in _globals ?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: I need to set this one: _global['__Zone_enable_cross_context_check']  Because otherwise i get an IE error.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/lib/browser/event-target.ts

Comment: On line 82 (delegate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`global` is `window` object in a browser as can be seen here:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (factory());
}(this,    <------------ `this` points to `window` in global scope
 (function () { 
   ...
});
```

so you can set the variable like this:

```
window['__Zone_disable_IE_check'] = true;
```

But you need to do that **before** `zone.js` is loaded. If you load `zone.js` in `index.html`, add the following:

```
<script>
    window['__Zone_disable_IE_check'] = true;
</script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at my related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675781/angular-4-app-using-ie-11-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script

Comment: I tried to put the window var before zone in the "polyfills.ts" file, where most (all?) of the JS is generated, I could see it (window['__Zone_enable_cross_context_check'] = true;) in the web source code, put didn't work.

Comment: put in the in the `index.html` before all polyfills are loaded. putting it in the `polyfills.ts` won't work because all imports are executed before the `polyfills.ts`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have had to uncomment the following line in the polyfills file:

```
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
```

Project Angular version: Angular 6.0.1